# HTML elements not lining up when text is too long

Tags: html, css, twig

I am using Twig Templates with scss and js files. I created a twig template for Bootstrap popovers. The popover information is formatted correctly in most cases. However, it seems that when some text becomes too long, specifically the Instructor Info `<p>` tag, the alignment gets altered.

The correct layout. @ is the icon.

```
@ Header Text
  Instructor info text
  text text text text text text

@ Header Text
  Instructor info text
  text text text text text text
```

The error case

```
@ 
Header Text
Longer than average Instructor info text 
text text text text text text

@ Header Text
  Instructor info text 
  text text text text text text
```

The twig and html

```
{% embed 'fragments/popover.html.twig' %}
    {% block link_class %}more-sections{% endblock %}
    {% block link_text %}
        <span class="fa fa-info-circle"></span>
    {% endblock %}

{% block title %}Contact Info{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    {% for ArrayIndex in 0..(section.getInstructorNamesArrayCount()-1)  %}
    <div>
        <span class="fa fa-user instructor-contact-info-header"></span>
        <div class="contact-info-container">
            <p class="instructor-contact-info-header">{{section.getInstructorNamesArray()[namesArrayIndex]}}</p>
            <p class="instructor-contact-info-data">{{ section.getInstructorInfo()[namesArrayIndex] }}</p>
            <p class="instructor-contact-info-data" style="color: #005993; margin: 0;" >{{ section.getInstructorEmails[namesArrayIndex] }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
   {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

CSS

```
.instructor-contact-info-header {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #005993;
  margin: 0;
}

.instructor-contact-info-data {
  margin: 0;
}

.contact-info-container {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

EDIT:: Below is the rendered code for one block of info that produces the

```
<div class="popover-inner-content ">                                                                                
<div>
    <span class="fa fa-user instructor-contact-info-header"></span>
    <div class="contact-info-container">
        <p class="instructor-contact-info-header">LASTNAME, S.</p>
        <p class="instructor-contact-info-data">Title, Department of..., Statistics</p>
        <p class="instructor-contact-info-data" style="color: #005993; margin: 0;" >email@email.com</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is the rendered code second contact information that produces the correct layout

```
<div class="contact-info-container">
    <p class="instructor-contact-info-header">LASTNAME, D.</p>
    <p class="instructor-contact-info-data">Statistics</p>
    <p class="instructor-contact-info-data" style="color: #005993; margin: 0;" >name@email.com</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have a live version of the rendered code that we could review? This will help us better visualize the problems you are encountering.

Comment: Edited to include the rendered code. Let me know if more info is needed

Comment: it seems as though all my popover elements with the issue have a width of 276px. Perhaps theres a cap on bootstrap popover width which is causing this?